# send data to asp.net core Api from browser url

Tags: asp.net, api, asp.net-core, url, postman

I want to send data from browser url to my SqlServer database. almost all video in youtube use postman  but i don't want to use that. here is my class [image]

The server Address is ***https://localhost:44378/api/Home*** . How can i data from browser url ?

Comment: Perhaps, i should use [FromRoute] attribute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to pass data via query string.For example

```
https://localhost:44378/api/Home?Id=1&&Tempreture=20&&Humidiy=1&&LightIntensity=2
```

Comment: Thanks, it work's fine. note that in api method we should write [Fromquery] attribute

Comment: If it is helpful,can you mark it as answer?Thank you.

Comment: Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) about how to accept an answer on stackoverflow.